# Pro-tem moderator appointment date is hard to parse and should either follow ISO 8601 or state only the year

Tags: feature-request, moderators, beta-phase, dates

The pro-tem moderator appointment date is currently shown in middle-endian notation (%m/%d/%y).  For example, see [Outdoors.SE moderators](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators):

[image: Screenshot]

I find `6/5/2014` ambiguous and hard to parse.  From the other appointments, I can infer that it must be the middle-endian `%m/%d/%y`, so that this really means 2014-06-05, which is arguably [the only correct date notation](https://xkcd.com/1179/).  Another alternative would be to only mark the year, such as for elected moderators on graduated sites.

Comment: Perhaps we should use the same date format as usercards i.e Aug 16 '18

Comment: @RobertLongson Which on hover-over reveal the ISO-standard date notation!  That hover-over would be an improvement already.